# Custom Button style is appearing in preview but not on device API 27

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles, android-studio-3.2

I created a custom button, it is appearing in the preview, but not on my phone. The minimum API is 17 and my phone's API is 27.

```
//custom button
<style name="taskButton"  parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentStart">true</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">-3dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/Red</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
</style>

//xml 
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                style="@style/taskButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: The button is not appearing or the style is not set correctly?

Comment: the button is appearing,but not with the right style

Comment: What theme is the Button being inflated with? Probably this is just your Activity's theme, but it could be different if the Button tag has a parent with the `android:theme: attribute (or if your LayoutInflater has a theme set explicitly).

Comment: And, I suppose, what theme does that theme derive from? The important piece of information I'm looking from here is if you're using an AppCompat theme, a MaterialComponents theme, or something else.

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out the problem.
I had 2 xml files, one for api 21+ and another one for api 21-.
I deleted both, and recreated a new one for all the versions. And my issue is fixed.